# How to include <stdio> in xcode? C++

Tags: c++, xcode, stdio

How do you do

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

in xcode?

I get all these errors.

[image]

Comment: Do yo have Command Line Tools installed?

Comment: How do I check? btw what i did was xcode->new->project->OSX Application->command line tool

Comment: Run '$ xcode-select -p' in a terminal, what's the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `std::ofstream` you `#include <fstream>`.
For `std::string` you `#include <string>`.

`<stdio.h>` is a C header needed for functions such as `printf` or `fopen`. It's included like this: `#include <stdio.h>`. In C++ it's better to `#include <cstdio>` instead, so all names are embedded in `namespace std` (so you should use `std::printf` etc).

Answer (score -1):

You're a C programmer huh?

`<stdio.h>` is C's I/O library. I think you're looking for this (C++'s I/O library):

```
#include <iostream>
```